# Помогите определиться со знаками препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста,определиться со знаками препинания, даже не знаю какое правило открыть, чтобы понять как оформить.

> Первый вопрос, который  возникнет – это на какой инструмент нацеливаться –   импортный или отечественный?

Тире, запятые, как быть?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

**Первый вопрос, который возникнет: на какой инструмент нацеливаться – импортный или отечественный?**

Содержание вопроса лучше поместить после двоеточия, а перечисление отделить от обобщающего слова с помощью тире.

> Примечание. Допустимо используемое в современной практике печати при всех позициях обобщающих слов употребление тире , в том числе – перед перечислением (на месте традиционного двоеточия): В новом цехе организуется массовое производство изделий для машиностроения – втулок, стаканов, зубчатых сеток ([Знаки препинания при однородных членах предложения](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/))

Другой вариант ближе к разговорной речи:

**Первый вопрос, который возникнет, — это на какой инструмент нацеливаться: импортный или отечественный.**

Запятая и тире ставятся по принципу: каждый знак по своей причине.  После обобщающего слова употреблено традиционное двоеточие. Знак вопроса я убрал, так как здесь скорее дано описание вопроса, нежели сам вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

**Первый вопрос, который возникнет, – это на какой инструмент нацеливаться, импортный или отечественный?**

Здесь позицию сказуемого заменяет вопросительное предложение.

Придаточное предложение ***который возникнет*** обособляется с двух сторон.

**Второе тире** можно без проблем заменить запятой (это единая фраза *импортный или отечественный,* произносится без паузы).

**Стиль речи разговорный,** что видно по глаголу "нацеливаться", поэтому менять структуру предложения нет смысла.